# How to prevent docker containers auto-start at daemon start in Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, docker-compose

I am using Docker and its docker-compose functionalities on Windows 10.

Right now when I run the command `docker-compose up -d` to start some containers in the background, the containers started will be running even after rebooting my Docker-Host.

How can I prevent that? I just want them to start when I explicitly power them up.

Comment: How is this off topic?  If anything its a duplicate.

Comment: Agreed. It could hardly be MORE on-topic, although neither the question nor the answer is Windows-specific.

Answer (score 7):

You can easily achieve this by using the following command:

> docker update --restart=no *my-container*

Where *my-container* should be every container you don't want to be started when your Host (In this case W10) boots.

Comment: I found this answer in the following Stackoverflow Post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513545/how-to-prevent-docker-from-starting-a-container-automatically-on-system-startup